# Exercises on nets

Tags: general-topology, nets

well I'm learning nets  with Munkres, but I'd like to do more exercises than those in this book. Any web site or reference would be welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Section 4.3 of Folland's *Real Analysis* is on nets, and there are some exercises at the end. I'm not sure how they compare with those in Munkres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was answered in a comment:

> Section 4.3 of Folland's *Real Analysis* is on nets, and there are some exercises at the end. I'm not sure how they compare with those in Munkres. –  Keenan Kidwell Feb 2 at 3:30

Answer (score 2):

Stephen Willard's *General Topology* has chapters on nets and filters with a lot of nice exercises.